# What is the difference between android.permission and ANDROID.PERMISSION

Tags: android

I am working with a project that contains imageloader through Picasso API.

When I try to add uses-permission of INTERNET through 
android.permission.INTERNET

it works perfectly but when i use ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Android is case-sensitive. `android.permission.INTERNET` is the proper value.

You may be encountering [this code-completion bug in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173977).

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, permissions are case sensitive.

In the case of the `INTERNET` permission, the permission is defined as [`android.permission.INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET). If your casing does not match how the permission is defined, the framework doesn't know what permission you are trying to request.

Note that application developers can define permissions however they want, but the convention is `<packagename>.PERMISSION_NAME`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But what does ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET actually do

Comment: `ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET` isn't a part of the framework at all. My guess is that you encountered it via [the bug that CommonsWare linked to in his answer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173977). `android.permission.INTERNET` on the other hand is simply a string that identifies a permission that the Android framework has defined.

Answer (score 0):

In a case-sensitive language, `a` is 97 and `A` is 65. They are different.